# Image Chart with custom icons

Tags: php, javascript, charts, google-visualization

[image]

I want to make image chart similar to the above one.

Q: Is there any (PHP or JS) library which gives facility to add custom icons for image charts ?

Q: Where to start if I need to create such charts using PHP ? How about thinking of new own library in PHP ?

Q: Any other solution/suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html ?

Comment: @Milap: That offers only available custom icons, I didn't get way to display thumb icons.

Comment: anyone experienced http://jpgraph.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `Highcharts`. Its easy to use, can be used with `php` and it supports symbols as markers. Check out this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/LYpdt/) here.

Comment: Highcharts gives you options to export your chart as image in various formats.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/column-chart-with-images-on-top/